# List files beginning with underscores first when using `ls -l`

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04, ls

I'm using ubuntu (natty), and when I use `ls -l`, the files are listed, but apparently the sorting algo ignores any special characters. For ages I've used underscores to mark special folders. And it seems to me, that they were always listed first.

Now, the underscore is completely ignores.

Let's assume that I have the files `fileA`, `_fileB` and `fileC` in a folder. Currently, `ls -l` orders them like so:

```
malbert@dredg:/tmp/1$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 malbert domain users 0 2011-08-03 15:27 fileA
-rw-r--r-- 1 malbert domain users 0 2011-08-03 15:27 _fileB
-rw-r--r-- 1 malbert domain users 0 2011-08-03 15:27 fileC
```

But I'd like it to be sorted like follows:

```
malbert@dredg:/tmp/1$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 malbert domain users 0 2011-08-03 15:27 _fileB
-rw-r--r-- 1 malbert domain users 0 2011-08-03 15:27 fileA
-rw-r--r-- 1 malbert domain users 0 2011-08-03 15:27 fileC
```

I've dug through the `ls` man page and could not find anything. Is there somewhere a system-wide `collation` option? Or something the like?

Comment: Are you sure you do not have something like `alias ls='ls -U'` in your startup script ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I imagine it obeys the setting of `LC_COLLATE` in your environment or, in the absence of that, the setting of `LC_ALL` or `LANG` instead.

The `locale(1)` command should tell you what settings a program will see, given your environment.

Comment: Yes. Setting `LC_COLLATE` to `C` fixed it. Thanks a bunch :)